# Converting Pecl HTTP 1 to Pecl HTTP 2.0

Tags: php, http, pecl

One of my servers was just upgraded to use Pecl http 2.0x and so now my http 1.0 code is totally broken.  The code I had working before was this:

```
http_send_content_disposition($filename,true);
http_send_content_type('video/mp4');
http_send_file($file);
```

And so I am attempting to convert this to the 2.0 Pecl HTTP code and it is not working.  Here's what I have so far:

```
$res = new http\Env\Response;
$res->setContentType('video/mp4');
$res->setContentDisposition(["filename" => $filename]);     
$fp = fopen($file,"r");
$res->send($fp);
```

Does anyone know what the proper translation would be?  The documentation for this new version is horrible and they don't provide any upgrade path from 1.0.

Thanks!